# jqgrid columns not sorting when clicked

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following block of code:

```
$("#searchlist").jqGrid({
                url:'./searchlibrary',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                postData: {type: function(){return $('select[name="searchtype"]').val();},
                    criteria: function(){return getSearchData();}
                },
                colNames:['Resource Name','Unit', 'Topic','Document Type','Content Type','Select'],
                colModel :[ 
                  {name:'resourceName', index:'resourceName', width:380, align:'left'}, 
                  {name:'unit', index:'unitID', width:40, align:'center',sortable:true}, 
                  {name:'topic', index:'topicID', width:220, align:'center',sortable:true}, 
                  {name:'docType', index:'docTypeID', width:97, align:'center',sortable:true}, 
                  {name:'contentType', index:'contentTypeID', width:97, align:'center',sortable:true},
                  {name: 'select', index:'resourceID', width:55, align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value:"Yes:No", defaultValue:"No" }, formatter:"checkbox",formatoptions: {disabled : false}}
                ],
                rowNum:20,
                sortname: 'resourceName',
                sortorder: 'asc',
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                width:878,
                height:251,
                loadComplete: function(data){
                    initCheckboxes();
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(ev){
                        initCheckboxes();
                    });
                }
             });
```

The data loads just fine, however when I click the various column headers they don't sort. The loading box shows up briefly over the data, but the columns never actually re-sort. The only column that the sort works on is the very first column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `index` property you set for other columns are different compared to the column name. When you sort a particular column jQGrid passes the value you set at the index as the sort parameter (sidx).

Comment: That was it! Thanks. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index` property you set for other columns are different compared to the column name. When you sort a particular column jQGrid passes the value you set at the index as the sort parameter (sidx).

```
$("#searchlist").jqGrid({
    ...
    colModel :[ 
        {name:'resourceName', index:'resourceName', width:380, align:'left'}, 
        {name:'unit', index:'unit', width:40, align:'center',sortable:true}, 
        {name:'topic', index:'topic', width:220, align:'center',sortable:true}, 
        {name:'docType', index:'docType', width:97, align:'center',sortable:true}, 
        {name:'contentType', index:'contentType', width:97, align:'center',sortable:true},
        {name: 'select', index:'select', width:55, align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value:"Yes:No", defaultValue:"No" }, formatter:"checkbox",formatoptions: {disabled : false}}
    ],
    ...
});
```